# check if float is integer

Tags: python, isinteger

I have a variable score wich increases over time I but would like to print only the integer ones. like 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 et cetera.

```
    score += 0.5
    if score.is_integer:
        print(score)
```

But actually every score is printed.

```
0.5
1.0
1.5
2.0
2.5
3.0
3.5
4.0
4.5
5.0
5.5
6.0
6.5
7.0
7.5
8.0
8.5
9.0
9.5
```

What do I miss here?

Comment: you need to call the function: `if score.is_integer():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if int(score) == score:
```

this should work fine or just follow the comment by @Robin Zigmond ie.,

```
if score.is_integer():
```

Comment: I have not enough reputations to cast an upvote.

Comment: no worries. But i think you can mark it as accepted. keep learning...

Comment: BTW just an extra tip regarding the answer, if the score variable is some string which cannot be casted to an int (e.g, 'abcd'), it will throw an error, to prevent that, use try except

Comment: I will do so. Thank  you for the advice I will keep that in mind.